# flot: integration example with fancybox and like?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, flot

I'm using flot to display a set of graphs on a web page. Now I'm looking for a floating window that's quite popular these days, like those used for showing a gallery.

fancybox looks quite nice and capable. My question is: has anybody used fancybox to display a flot picture and would like to share how easy/hard it was?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy to combine the two.  [I coded this up in about 10 mins.](http://jsfiddle.net/vB5Me/)

Comment: Nice. The link doesn't seem to work with Chrome for some reason.